# Functionality When Hiding Div Not Working Correctly

Tags: jquery, html, postback, show

I have the following (brief) concept on a page:

I have 5 checkboxes, depending on which checkboxes are checked, I display a div corresponding to the checkbox select (i.e if I select Test CheckBox Two then a div displays corresponding to that).

I can hide and show the div without any problem when clicking on the checkbox. The problem I have is that at some point during the process the user opens a modal screen, and when this is closed the page does a postback/reloads. Then, regardless of which checkboxes are checked the divs are hidden.

I'm assuming this is because I call the function on the click event of the checkbox. I need to same divs that were selected to display when the opened modal closes, without having to re-click the checkboxes.

My html:

```
 <input type="checkbox" runat="server" id="cbImplement" class="selectCriteria" title="Implementation" value="cbImplement" /><span style="font-weight: bold; color: #4b6c9e">Implement</span>

<ul id="ulTabs">
    <li class="displayItem" id="liImplement" style="display: none"><a href="#divImplement">
        <span style="font-weight: bold; color: #4b6c9e;">Implement</span></a></li>
</ul>

<div id="divImplement" class="divframe"></div>
```

My jquery:

```
     $(".selectCriteria").click(function () {
         var id = $(this).attr('id'); // get checkbox id

       if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        // Show Implementation
           if (checkboxID == "cbImplement") {
               $('#liImplement').show();
               $('#divImplement').show();
        }
    }
    else{
        // Hide Implementation
        if (checkboxID == "cbImplement") {
            $('#liImplement').hide();
            $('#divImplement').hide();
        }
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the page to execute a function every time the page is loaded, and show divs. This way, when the page is first loaded, the checkboxes are unchecked and the divs hidden. On page reload after the modal screen is closed the function gets executed again and shows the hidden divs.